# When I insert data using PHP it insert more than 10 same data in my table?

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to create a visitor counter, when user visit the page it will record the time and the number of visitor. But when I refresh the page, my database will be like this:
[image]

The code that I do is:

```
if (empty($counter)){
        $counter = 1;
        $total = 1;
        $time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $sql1 = "INSERT INTO humancount(counter, time, totalHumanCount) VALUES ('$counter', '$time', '$total)";
        $result1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql1);
    }

    //date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');
    $date1 = strtotime("now");
    $date2 = strtotime("tomorrow");
    echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date1);
    echo "<br>";
    echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date2);
    if ($date1 < $date2){
        $plusCounter = $counter + 1;
        $plusTotal = $total + 1;
        $nextTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $sql2 = "UPDATE humancount SET counter='$plusCounter', time='$nextTime', totalHumanCount='$plusTotal'";
        $result2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2);
    }
```

I was expecting that it will record the time of the user visit by every row.

Comment: Since there is `if(empty($counter)) { ...` I assume you are first fetching the max counter value from the DB?

Comment: My thought was, if there is no values in the DB, then counter will be 1

Comment: Are you first fetching the value of the counter?

Comment: Yes, I am first fetching it

Comment: Try the solution from my answer below, it should work for your scenario.

Comment: I edited again to further simplify the code, since you really need only one insert statement and one `$time` variable.

Comment: It's work, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code is overwriting every row in the table with the current counter update:

```
$sql2 = "UPDATE humancount SET counter='$plusCounter', time='$nextTime', totalHumanCount='$plusTotal'";
```

you should instead insert a new row for each new visitor.

Also, this will always be true:

```
if ($date1 < $date2)
```

so you can remove the `if` statement.

You can do something like this:

```
//first fetch the last values from the database
$sql0 = "SELECT counter, totalHumanCount FROM humancount ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql0);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $counter = $row['counter'] + 1;
    $total = $row['totalHumanCount'] + 1;
} else {
    $counter = 1;
    $total = 1;
}

//date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');
$time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO humancount(counter, time, totalHumanCount) VALUES ('$counter', '$time', '$total)";
$result1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Where condition in UPDATE query. as per your query every time it will update all rows in table 'humancount'. so add UserID column for unique row and then update row for selected user.

$sql2 = "UPDATE humancount SET counter='$plusCounter', time='$nextTime', totalHumanCount='$plusTotal' **WHERE userID = ?**";